# index is returning wrong value i.e. 1 instead of 0

Tags: java

When i debug this code with nums={3,2,4} target = 6, for key = 3 , i am getting the index value as 1 instead of 0 ? Can someone pls tell me why ?

```
class Main {
        public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
            HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
            for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++) {
                map.put(nums[i],nums[i]);
            }
            Set<Integer> set = map.keySet();
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(set);
            
            for(int i=0;i<nums.length-1;i++) {
                if(map.containsKey(target-nums[i])) {
                    int key = map.get(target-nums[i]);
                    int index = list.indexOf(key);
                    if(index != i) {
                        nums = new int[2];
                        nums[0] = i;
                        nums[1] = index;
                    }
                }
            }
            return nums;
        }                               
    }
```

Comment: Unless you need methods that only the implementation has to offer it is standard practice to assign to an interface type.  So `Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();` is preferred.  The same for `Lists` and `Sets`.  Also note you don't need to specify the content types between the `<>` on the right side of the assignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HashMap` and `HashSet` do not maintain the insertion order. If you want to preserve the insertion order, you need to use `LinkedHashMap` and `LinkedHashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

You can map the array index to its value in the initial loop to preserve it here's my solution from leetcode. Your problem is fixed with correcting the hashmap itself

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] arr, int target) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            map.put(arr[i], i);
    }
    
    for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; ++j) {
        int compliment = target - arr[j];
        if (map.containsKey(compliment) == true && map.get(compliment) != j){
            return new int[] {map.get(compliment), j };
        }
    }
        
    
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Target");
}
```